# gfci breakers vs afci / dfci

Tags: gfci

If I use GFCI breakers do I still need GFCI receptacles? Also I see some combonation AFCI / GFCI breakers. Are these reliable?
And my last question of the weeek. Is the home run in a branch circuit a seperate neutral wire which connects the last receptacle / switch to the neutral bus?

Answer (score 3):

If you use a GFCI breaker, you don't need GFCI receptacles. As long as the breaker provides the level of protection required at the outlet.

Dual Function Circuit Interrupter (DFCI) breakers are reliable.

"*Home run*" is not a technical term. It may be used to describe a dedicated circuit, where the circuit only supplies a single device. It may also describe branch circuit conductors, that run uninterrupted from the panel to the first device.